# Pivotal GPDB - psql error -could not open file for reading: No such file or directory

Tags: talend, greenplum, hawq

I am trying to import data from csv file to a gpdb table, but COPY command fails with "No such file or directory" error message - despite the fact
that the file I am trying to read is definitely there.

**scenario**

We are trying to write the data into  target system called "pivotal greenplum database" using Talend tool from source called SQL server.

In that , data flow component called tGreenplumBulkExec throwing

**Error:**

```
    tGreenplumBulkExec_1|org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:ERROR: 
could not open file "/path/to/file.csv" for reading: No such file or directory|1
```

**Talend data flow :**

Read from SQL server -->write into hdfs -->tmap-->tGreenplumOutputBulk-->tGreenplumBulkExec

**Detailed stacktrace**

```
Exception in component tGreenplumBulkExec_1
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not open file/path/to/file.csv for reading: No such file or directory
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1592)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1327)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:192)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:451)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:336)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:328)
    at bigdata.jobname_0_1.jobname.tGreenplumBulkExec_1Process(jobname.java:10080)
    at bigdata.jobname_0_1.jobname.tJDBCInput_1Process(jobname.java:9783)
    at bigdata.jobname_0_1.jobname.runJobInTOS(jobname.java:11692)
    at bigdata.jobname_0_1.jobname.main(jobname.java:11431)
2017-02-04 13:29:39|eAM8VI|eAM8VI|eAM8VI|BIGDATA|jobname|Default|6|Java Exception|tGreenplumBulkExec_1|org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:ERROR: could not open file "/path/to/file.csv" for reading: No such file or directory|1
[statistics] disconnected
Job jobname ended at 13:29 04/02/2017. [exit code=1]
```

**We tried:**

```
Path permission of Input file already checked.
Double checked the file path in talend component setting.
```

Any help would be much appreciated in it ?

Comment: it may be looking for the directory on the sql server not the local Talend run server.  also, if you are using a remote execution server it may be looking there.

Comment: Have you looked at Outsourcer?

Comment: Copied File from Windows To Linux using pscp command :pscp -pw password C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.txt  \ user@192.168.33.10:/home/gpadmin/sor.csv

Comment: getting this error :Java.io.FileNotFoundException:\home\gpadmin\sor.csv (The system cannot find the path specified)|1

Comment: why do you use a tGreenplumBulkExec to extract a csv. Use a tDelimitedFileInput instead and after the extraction you can load into greeplum

Comment: Take a look at Greenplum GPLoad. (There is a component for that.) That is the preferred way to push data into greenplum. Copy overloads the master node, while gpload uses backdoors and pushes data directly to the segments.